# Why is $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{x+\alpha}dx \le \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Found in my course notes: "$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{x+\alpha}dx \le \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$"

My conjecture: $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{x+\alpha}dx = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{x+\alpha}\cdot x^{100}dx \le \int\limits_0^1 \lvert \frac{1}{x+\alpha}\lvert \cdot \lvert x^{100}\lvert dx \le \int\limits_0^1 \lvert \frac{1}{x+\alpha}\lvert \cdot \lvert 1\lvert dx$

But how do we go from there?

Comment: *Hint.* $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x+\alpha}$ is increasing for $x \geq 0$. And using this, you can even show that $$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x+\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{1}{n(1+\alpha)} $$ for $n > 0$ and $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: since the integral is a "continuous" summation over an interval, $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{x+\alpha}dx$ has $\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$ as its largest term, and then infinitely many other terms in the sum. That is, $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{x+\alpha}dx = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}+...+\frac{0.5^{100}}{0.5+\alpha}+...+\frac{0^{100}}{0+\alpha} > \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$, correct?